# Reason for Scala's Map.unzip returning (Iterable, Iterable)

Tags: scala, dictionary, unspecified-behavior

the other day I was wondering why scala.collection.Map defines its unzip method as

```
def unzip [A1, A2] (implicit asPair: ((A, B)) ⇒ (A1, A2)): (Iterable[A1], Iterable[A2])
```

Since the method returns "only" a pair of Iterable instead of a pair of Seq it is not guaranteed that the key/value pairs in the original map occur at matching indices in the returned sequences since Iterable doesn't guarantee the order of traversal. So if I had a

```
Map((1,A), (2,B))
```

, then after calling

```
Map((1,A), (2,B)) unzip
```

I might end up with

```
... = (List(1, 2),List(A, B))
```

just as well as with

```
... = (List(2, 1),List(B, A))
```

While I can imagine storage-related reasons behind this (think of HashMaps, for example) I wonder what you guys think about this behavior. It might appear to users of the Map.unzip method that the items were returned in the same pair order (and I bet this is probably almost always the case) yet since there's no guarantee this might in turn yield hard-to-find bugs in the library user's code.

Maybe that behavior should be expressed more explicitly in the accompanying scaladoc?

**EDIT: Please note that I'm not referring to maps as *ordered* collections.** I'm only interested in "matching" sequences after unzip, i.e. for

```
val (keys, values) = someMap.unzip
```

it holds for all i that (keys(i), values(i)) is an element of the original mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the examples you gave will not occur. The `Map` will always be unzipped in a pair-wise fashion. Your statement that `Iterable` does not guarantee the ordering, is not entirely true. It is more accurate to say that any given `Iterable` does not have to guarantee the ordering, but this is dependent on implementation. In the case of `Map.unzip`, the ordering of pairs is not guaranteed, but items in the pairs will not change they way they are matched up -- that matching is a fundamental property of the `Map`. You can read [the source](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src//library/scala/collection/generic/GenericTraversableTemplate.scala#L76) to `GenericTraversableTemplate` to verify this is the case.

Answer (score 4):

If you expand `unzip`'s description, you'll get the answer:

```
definition classes: GenericTraversableTemplate
```

In other words, it didn't get specialized for `Map`.

Your argument is sound, though, and I daresay you might get your wishes if you open an enhancement ticket with your reasoning. Specially if you go ahead an produce a patch as well -- if nothing else, at least you'll learn a lot more about Scala collections in doing so.

Answer (score 3):

Maps, generally, do not have a natural sequence: they are unordered collections. The fact your keys happen to have a natural order does not change the general case.

(However I am at a loss to explain why Map has a `zipWithIndex` method. This provides a counter-argument to my point. I guess it is there for consistency with other collections and that, although it provides indices, they are not guaranteed to be the same on subsequent calls.)

Comment: It's best to think of `zipWithIndex` as just a convenient helper. It's not saying anything in particular about the ordering of the `Map`, it's just providing a handy mechanism that is too often rewritten in languages that don't provide a similar call.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, the OP didn't assume maps as *ordered* collections.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a LinkedHashMap or LinkedHashSet the iterators are supposed to return the pairs in the original order of insertion.  Other HashMaps, yeah, you have no control.  Retaining the original order of insertion is quite useful in UI contexts, it allows you to resort tables on any column in a Web application without changing types, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for answering. It's not the insertion order, however, that I'm trying to maintain. Please see above EDIT to the OP.